# Pickle Does not save instance of object

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pickle

I have a custom model collaborative.py and it contains following code

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import pickle

class LatentCollaborativeFiltering():

    def __init__(self, numberOfRecommendations, stepSize, lamda, gamma, K):
        self.ratings_data = pd.read_csv('../data/ratings.csv')
        self.movies_data = pd.read_csv('../data/movies.csv')
        self.numberOfRecommendations = numberOfRecommendations
        self.steps = stepSize
        self.lamda = lamda 
        self.gamma = gamma 
        self.K = K
        self.R = self.read_data()
        self.N = len(self.R.index)
        self.M = len(self.R.columns)
        self.P = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(self.N, self.K), index = self.R.index)
        self.Q = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(self.M, self.K), index = self.R.columns)
        print("Csv file read successful and R matrix formed")
        self.MatrixFactorization() 

    def read_data(self):
        data = pd.merge(self.ratings_data, self.movies_data, left_on="movieId", right_on="movieId")
        data=pd.DataFrame.sort_values(data,['userId','movieId'],ascending=[0,1])
        R = pd.pivot_table(data, values='rating', index=['userId'], columns = ['movieId'])
        print("User Item Rating Matrix Returned")
        return R

    def MatrixFactorization(self):
        self.R = self.R.iloc[:10, :10]
        for step in range(self.steps):
            for i in self.R.index:
                for j in self.R.columns:
                    if self.R.loc[i,j]>0:
                        # For each rating that exists in the training set 
                        eij=self.R.loc[i,j]-np.dot(self.P.loc[i],self.Q.loc[j])
                        self.P.loc[i]=self.P.loc[i]+self.gamma*(eij*self.Q.loc[j]-self.lamda*self.P.loc[i])
                        self.Q.loc[j]=self.Q.loc[j]+self.gamma*(eij*self.P.loc[i]-self.lamda*self.Q.loc[j])
            e=0
            for i in self.R.index:
                for j in self.R.columns:
                    if self.R.loc[i,j]>0:
                        #Sum of squares of the errors in the rating
                        e= e + pow(self.R.loc[i,j]-np.dot(self.P.loc[i],self.Q.loc[j]),2)+self.lamda*(pow(np.linalg.norm(self.P.loc[i]),2)+pow(np.linalg.norm(self.Q.loc[j]),2))
                        print("Error", e)
            if e<0.001:
                print(e)
                break
            print(step)
        return self.P,self.Q


    def predict(self, activeUser):
        self.predictItemRating=pd.DataFrame(np.dot(self.P.loc[activeUser],self.Q.T),index=self.Q.index,columns=['Rating'])
        self.topRecommendations=pd.DataFrame.sort_values(self.predictItemRating,['Rating'],ascending=[0])[:3]
        self.topRecommendationTitles=self.movies_data.loc[self.movies_data.movieId.isin(self.topRecommendations.index)]
        return list(self.topRecommendationTitles.title)

myobj = LatentCollaborativeFiltering(numberOfRecommendations=10, stepSize=100, lamda=0.02, gamma=0.001, K=2)
#result = myobj.predict(5)
#print(result)

with open('colla.pkl', 'wb') as outfile:
    my_model = pickle.dump(myobj, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I have created a myobj object of a class and dumped the object as pickle file. But when I load the pickle file the object does not load from the previous state and perform all the computation again. Whant I want is to perform the computation only once when the object gets initialized and not again and again to call the predict function inside the class. Any suggestions would be really helpful. My script to load the pickled object is

```
import pickle 
from collaborative import LatentCollaborativeFiltering

with open('colla.pkl', 'rb') as infile:
    myObj = pickle.load(infile)

print(myObj.predict(5))
```

Here when running this script the whole process of matrix factorization again takes place.

Comment: you shouldn't hardcode `pd.read_csv` in the constructor

Comment: I will pass the data as arguments then. any other suggestions?

Comment: customizing the state of pickled/unpickled objects is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects)